# How to handle an android.ui.seekbar.TwowaySeekbar from Selendroid

Tags: android, selendroid

Please tell me how to handle this element type from selendroid.
Following is the xml design of the element:

```
    android:id="@+id/twowaySeekbar1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, there is no `TwowaySeekbar` in Android. Second, what do you mean by "handle"? Please explain **completely and precisely** what you have tried and what problems you are encountering.

Comment: I agree. It is a customized element class which extends the class View. [public class SListView extends View]

Comment: Please consider this element. This is the xml code-->  <com.a.android.ui.scrollablelist.SListView
                            android:id="@+id/year"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.32" />                                     This element is basically a roller. I need to scroll the element and select a value displayed.